# Laravel reset password email is not working on production

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I get this error when i try go to forgot password and enter my email in my laravel application :

> Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::removeChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456138/laravel-reset-password-argument-1-passed-to-domnoderemovechild-must-be-an-i) earlier today but got no reponses.
(Please read the question and the comments.)
So i am adding more details to the question and because the older question might not get much attention now, i am asking a new one.

I started tracing the request and dumping the variables to see the where the difference is, between the production and the local machine.
(By the way the production and local servers both have same php version now.)

There is this function in

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Markdown.php

```
/**
 * Render the Markdown template into HTML.
 *
 * @param  string  $view
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  \TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles|null  $inliner
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function render($view, array $data = [], $inliner = null)
{
    $this->view->flushFinderCache();
    $contents = $this->view->replaceNamespace(
        'mail', $this->htmlComponentPaths()
    )->make($view, $data)->render();

    return new HtmlString(($inliner ?: new CssToInlineStyles)->convert(
        $contents, $this->view->make('mail::themes.'.$this->theme)->render()
    ));
}
```

I dumped the variables `$view` and `$data` in both production and local, both giving the same values :

variable view : `"notifications::email"`

and

variable data :

```
array:8 [▼
  "level" => "info"
  "subject" => null
  "greeting" => null
  "salutation" => null
  "introLines" => array:1 [▶]
  "outroLines" => array:1 [▶]
  "actionText" => "Change Password"
  "actionUrl" => "http://localhost:8000/password/reset/ff6f1edf6793bf4fadf462781e5258980ddd3c94e545b3b9744b279842f75d93"
]
```

But when I dump the `$contents` variable, after this code segment :

```
$contents = $this->view->replaceNamespace(
    'mail', $this->htmlComponentPaths()
)->make($view, $data)->render();
```

the result is null in my server while in my local machine, it dumps a html of the email, which is what i want.

Does anybody see the issue here ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you verify that the mail template file exists on the server?

Comment: Maybe delete the vendor folder and reinstall the packages again with `composer update --prefer-source`